# FileReader().readAsArrayBuffer(file) result gets stuck after first loaded file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, filereader, arraybuffer

I'm using this code to generate an `md5` hash string to use as the file names in my storage. I read the file (image) contents and calculate the hash with the `md5` library.

Somehow the result of the method `readAsArrayBuffer(file)` of the `FileReader()` API is getting stuck after I read the first file.

**CodeSandBox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/file-reader-md5so-nem6v

If I change the reading method to `readAsText(file)` the results seems normal and I get a different hash for a different file. But I was told that `readAsArrayBuffer()` makes more sense for image files. That's why I'm using it.

What could be happening? Do I need to clear some buffer?

**GIF of the strange behavior:**

[image]

**EDIT:** It turns out you need to create a typed array from the `ArrayBuffer` to work with the results from `readAsArrayBuffer()`

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer

> The ArrayBuffer object is used to represent a generic, fixed-length raw binary data buffer.
>
> It is an array of bytes, often refered to in other languages as a "byte array".
>
> **You cannot directly manipulate the contents of an ArrayBuffer; instead, you create one of the typed array objects** or a DataView object which represents the buffer in a specific format, and use that to read and write the contents of the buffer.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import md5 from "md5";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([{ md5Hash: null }, { md5Hash: null }]);

  function onFileSelect(event, index) {
    console.log("onFileSelect...");
    generateHashAndSave(event.target.files[0], index);
  }

  function generateHashAndSave(file, index) {
    console.log("Generate Hash...");
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = event => {
      setImages(prevState => {
        const aux = Array.from(prevState);
        aux[index].md5Hash = md5(event.target.result);
        return aux;
      });
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }

  const inputItems = images.map((item, index) => (
    <input
      key={index}
      type="file"
      onChange={event => onFileSelect(event, index)}
      accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif"
    />
  ));

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {inputItems}
      <div><b>File 1 md5Hash: </b>{images[0].md5Hash}</div>
      <div><b>File 2 md5Hash: </b>{images[1].md5Hash}</div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what's going on, but it *looks* like a problem with the `md5()` library you're using. If you explicitly turn the `ArrayBuffer` instance into a `Uint8Array` then things aren't weird:

```
  aux[index].md5Hash = md5(new Uint8Array(event.target.result));
```

gives different hash values for different images.

It's possible that your `md5()` does not in fact expect `ArrayBuffer` arguments, so in that case it's not really a "bug" I suppose.

Comment: Thanks! The `md5` docs says it expects `String or Buffer`. Do you think this is the problem?

Comment: @cbdev420 well I'm not sure; all I know is that it works fine when you give it a typed array. It gave me the exact same not-really-a-hash value that you show in what you posted here, so that makes me think it's hashing some particular repeatable set of bytes from the `ArrayBuffer` instance; I don't know how or why.

Comment: @cbdev420 well *maybe*; the problem with non-text data like image data is that there could be unrecognizable UTF-16 sequences, and that might cause problems. I'm not sure. Making a new array shouldn't be that expensive; it doesn't have to allocate memory because the buffer is already there.

Comment: I guess you're right. The MDN docs about `ArrayBuffer` says: _You cannot directly manipulate the contents of an ArrayBuffer; instead, you create one of the typed array objects or a DataView object which represents the buffer in a specific format, and use that to read and write the contents of the buffer._

Comment: The best type array for me to use is the `Uint8array`? Or it doesn't really matter? `Int8`, `Int16`, `Int32` ?

Comment: Well `Uint8Array` seems to work so it's a strong contender :)  I doubt it matters as long as a given type seems to work (like, it matters if you get a runtime exception of some kind of course)